# how to make map overlap layout in view pager

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

i have nested fragment that contain mapview, all views are overlapping as i expected except mapview. i have a recyclerview too.. that display  under the cut layout, but map in not.

Screenshot:

result i get is :

[image]

and result what i expect:

[image]

i tried with setting nagative margin but its not work for mapview.

code:
fragment_around.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.stratafy.activities.SignupActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_aroundme">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/mProgressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#00000000"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextStyle2"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/ll1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"></LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/ll2"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"></LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/background"
        android:layout_marginTop="-90dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_filter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

margin-top = 160 start where floating button is.. and my map is at 240dp.

fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="-70dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user cut layout instead of RelativeLayout

```
public class CutLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private Xfermode pdMode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    private Path path = new Path();

    public CutLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CutLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CutLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CutLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        paint.setXfermode(pdMode);
        path.reset();

        path.moveTo(0, getHeight());
        path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight());
        path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight() - TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 60, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
        paint.setXfermode(null);
    } }
```

and in xml file

```
<com.helper.CutLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/aroundme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp" />
</com.helper.CutLayout>
```